# How to record sound use AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

when I record audio and play sound use the follow code

```
    SystemSoundID soundId
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundName ofType:_ext]
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path], &soundId)
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundId)
```

there are no sound will be play, is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: You can use AVAudioPlayer for play recording file

Comment: but AVAudioPlayer repeat play same source will cover the before sound